# Putting map on every page of variable multipage QGIS composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a composer in QGIS with variable page number (calculated from expression). I need to put a map composer item on every page automatically and use a unique id for each map item to automate further.

Unfortunately, Atlas feature doesn't suit this particular case, because I need to show all pages simultaneously and each page should have different content.

In my case number of composer pages is determined upon an expression involving an number of features in a layer and some project variables. I need particular elements (like tables, text, legend, etc.) appear only on particular pages. If I generate an Atlas, all these elements get generated on every page. This can't be controlled from gui because item "Page" property of "Position and Size" property group can't be set as expression. 
Also I need to be able to fine-tune each page separately and Atlas doesn't provide such option.

Comment: can you expand your question - especially as to why you can't generate each page separately using Atlas? What determines the number of pages? and the map contents?

Comment: Number of pages is determined upon an expression involving an number of features in a layer and some project variables. I need particular elements (like tables, text, legend, etc.) appear only on particular pages. If I generate an Atlas, all these elements get generated on every page because unfortunately item "Page" property of "Position and Size" property group can't be controlled by expression. Also I need to be able to fine-tune each page separately and Atlas doesn't provide such option.

Comment: @iant Edited my question. Are there any other details to be written to remove hold from this question? I've used Atlas a lot for other tasks and it really doesn't help in this case, though seems like it's the right way to go. I guess some scripting needs to be done here and I'd really like to get some directions at least.

Comment: One option would be to make the number of pages non-variable, using the maximum number of pages for each atlas feature. After the atlas is generated, manually delete the extra pages from the atlas output file.